# Possible forecast algorithms when time series is short with quarterly data spikes

Tags: r, time, series, short

I have an year s data with quarterly spikes, like below:

Sample code in R to create the dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame("Month" = c(1:12), "Count" = c(110,220,2500,150,180,1800,300,550,5000,205,313,4218))
```

Here is how the data looks:

```
Month Count
1         110
2         220
3        2500
4         150
5         180
6        1800
7         300
8         550
9        5000
10       205
11       313
12      4218
```

We can see that last month of every quarter has spike. My target is to forecast for next one year based on this data. I tried linear regression with some feature engineering (like how far a month is away from quarter) and results were obviously not satisfactory as it doesn't appear there is linear dependency.

I tried other techniques like seasonal naive and STLF (using R) and am currently going through few interpolation techniques (like lagrange or newtonInterpolation), there appears to be a lot of materials to study. Can anyone suggest a good possible solution for this so that I can explore further?

Comment: Isn't `stlf` operating for no-periodicity series? It looks like an ARIMA model could do the job here. In any case, [this](https://otexts.com/fpp2/) is my go to book when it comes to forecasting. The author is Rob Hyndman and the whole thing is centered around R and his package `forecast`

Comment: yes I too read that stlf is for no periodicity series. However it gave better results than Linear regression.

Comment: Isnt Arima an overkill for this? It cant pick seasonality as we just have an years data.

Comment: Another suggestion is to give it multiple frequencies. Maybe `c(3, 12)`...?

Comment: Ok... let me try that multiple frequencies option. Any ideas on interpolation techniques?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135061/best-method-for-short-time-series) could help.